# OpenCv Error while converting a Mat to Bitmap in Android

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap

I am trying to convert a Mat to Bitmap but am receiving an exception as follows:

```
E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3 || src.type() == CV_8UC4) in void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean), file /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp, line 98
```

Following is my code to convert a **camera captured** bitmap to a Mat.

```
public static Mat calculateHistogram(Bitmap bitmap) {
    MatOfFloat ranges = new MatOfFloat(0f, 255f);
    MatOfInt histSize = new MatOfInt(25);
    Mat imageMat = new Mat(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, imageMat);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(imageMat, imageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    Mat histoGramMat = new Mat();

    Imgproc.calcHist(Arrays.asList(imageMat), new MatOfInt(0), new Mat(), histoGramMat,
            histSize, ranges);
    return histoGramMat;
}
```

Now, when I try to convert this mat back to bitmap, I get the exception mentioned above. My code to convert a mat back to bitmap is as follows:

```
Bitmap resultBitmap = null;
            try {
                Mat temp = new Mat(comparisonMat.cols(), comparisonMat.rows(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
                comparisonMat.copyTo(temp);
                Imgproc.cvtColor(temp, temp, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
                resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(temp.cols(),
                        temp.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Utils.matToBitmap(temp, resultBitmap, true);
            }
            catch (CvException e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());
            }
```

Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: not sure about Java syntax, but normally cvMat constructor assumes height before width.

Comment: try Imgproc.cvtColor(temp, temp, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);  because you use ARGB_8888 which looks like 4 channel bitmap